# Evaluating expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

This code all works and produces 11 22 and 2032.

```
date = '11-22-2032'
mon, day, year = $1, $2, $3 if date =~ /(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/
p mon,day,year
```

But something like this won't work:

```
str = "This is a string"
str.gsub!(/(\w+)/, "1#{$1}")
p str => prints all whitespace
```

Does Ruby evaluates expressions starting from the right (thus the reason why the first example works?) How can I make the second example work (in the same .gsub method to make the word capture enclosed in () available, so I can add 1 before every word)?

Comment: `expression if condition` is just shorthand for `if condition; expression; end`.  It's not right to left, so much as a post conditional is evaluated first.  It's sort of a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact your second example does not work, has nothing to do with the order in which the `if` is being evaluated.

Instead, use `\1` and `\2` as interpolation variables.

```
str = "This is a string"
str.gsub!(/(\w+)/, '1\1')
print str
```

Also note that `"\1"` is interpolated, you need `'\1'`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) sets the global vars `$1`, `$2`, etc. in a way that can be used in the replacement string (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub). Instead, use backreferences `\1` (since you're including them in a double-quoted string, you need to double-escape as `"\\1"`):

```
>> str = "This is a string"
=> "This is a string"
>> str.gsub!(/(\w+)/, "1\\1")
=> "1This 1is 1a 1string"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't use `$1` this way is because you are passing the string as an arg into the `gsub` method, which means it, along with the interpolated `$1`, is evaluated *before* `gsub` gets to set and use it. @berkes's answer is one way and probably the best way to avoid that and to get the matched group(s).

But FYI you can also use a block:

```
str = "This is a string"
str.gsub!(/(\w+)/) {"1#{$1}"}
```

Because the block is evaluated only when called, which will be after `gsub` has already performed the match.